# find count of guesses with each element in code list but with different position python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am implementing a function named wrong_position(guess, code), which takes in the guessed number combination in the form of a list, (guess,) and the real combination in another list, (code), and returns how many numbers are correct but in the wrong place.

I have done so far :

````
def wrong_position(guess, code):
    if guess.count(guess[0]) == len(guess):
        return 0
    count = 0
    copy_code = []
    copy_guess = []
    for c in code:
        copy_code.append(c)

    for g in guess:
        copy_guess.append(g)
    for c in copy_guess:
        if c in copy_code:
            index1 = copy_guess.index(c)
            index2 = copy_code.index(c)
            if index1 != index2:
                copy_code[index2] = "*"
                count += 1
            else:
                copy_code[index2] = "*"
    return count```

but it failing following test cases 

In test nr 12 the function 'wrong_position fails', 
for code [2, 3, 3, 2] and guess [1, 1, 1, 2] it gives result 1 instead of 0
In test nr 13 the function 'wrong_position fails', 
for code [2, 3, 3, 2] and guess [1, 1, 3, 2] it gives result 2 instead of 0
In test nr 17 the function 'wrong_position fails', 
for code [9, 9, 9, 3] and guess [3, 9, 9, 2] it gives result 2 instead of 1
In test nr 20 the function 'wrong_position fails', 
for code [3, 5, 4, 4] and guess [1, 4, 2, 4] it gives result 2 instead of 1

i have given many hours to sort it out but failed
````

Answer (score 0):

i just change following and works,Thanks
`if index1 != index2:`
to
`if index1 != index2 and c != copy_code[i]:`